# How to get the actual control object from FieldInfo in .NET Reflection?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reflection, c#-4.0, controls, code-injection

I need to get the "control" object from the fieldInfo object in C# using reflection.

```
        Control mainControl = Control.FromHandle(a_hWnd);            
        object oMainControlObject = mainControl;

        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = oMainControlObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

For each fieldInfo in the fieldInfos array, I need to get the corresponding control object.

### My Attempts:

```
    Control oControl  = Control.FromHandle(fieldInfo.FieldHandle.Value); 
    Control oControl  = (Control)FieldInfo.GetValue(mainControl)
```

The first one returns NULL and the second one is not allowing me to typecast the above statement to control.

Regards,

Usman

Comment: Describe better what you try to do. It's very unclear to me and probably to others too.

Comment: Actaully I need to extract every control from .NET managed process, and these controls will be re-drawn by some other process and then these controls will be tested in this way.
For this i need to get every control on that managed process whether its form,button,textbox,label,combo,calander, image etc...) So everything is control actually.

Comment: In first step I am passing main form "control" on which every control resides, and after that I am reflecting and getting fields using control.GetType().GetFields(). So this way I am getting fields , bu in actual i NEED EVERY CONTROL's name,size,length,background and all its properties.

Comment: If you get what I desire, you probably tell me the right way to do the job.In .NET , automating GUI is the basic direction for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to recursively iterate through the `Controls` collection.

Comment: how can I get controls collection.

Comment: i mean using which object at which level?

Comment: you mean mainControl object(i.e form's main parent object) and iterating each control's object endlessly.?

Comment: One last question and i would then be obliged of you..:-)
So how these fieldInfo properties would be tie up with each control I mean? As I discover that each automating .NET app is playing around with this FieldInfo object ? How can we consume and use these fields along with each control then?